# plotly plotting in emr illeggal character error

Tags: python, plotly, amazon-emr

I am trying to use plotly in AWS EMR , As I have spark dataframe converting to python . From below code df is my pandas dataframe .

```
import pandas as pd
fig = px.bar(df, x='name', y='score',labels={'Features':'Importance'}, height=900)
fig.update_layout(title_text='Feature Importance')
fig.update_xaxes(tickangle=35)
fig.show()
```

When I plot something using emr I get error as below

```
 Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 27)): only regular white space (\r, \n, \t) is allowed between tokens   at [Source: Getting http://127.0.0.1:43463/; line: 1, column: 2]
```

Can anyone help me in crossing this hurdle

Comment: Hi @Naveen Srikanth I am facing the same issue as well. Were you able to get this fixed? If so, do you mind sharing the answer ? Thank you!

Comment: No I couldn't fix, For now As my data is small, I have uploaded manually to emr workspace . Created a new notebook with python3 interpretor and ran plotly graphs

Comment: Thank you for clarifying @Naveen Srikanth